# Unable to access desktop after latest NVIDIA update - 14.10

Tags: nvidia, 14.10, .desktop

I have a dual boot Sony Vaio F Series laptop (model # VPCF234FD). It runs Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.10. After my last update, which included an update of my NVIDIA drivers, if I'm not mistaken, I'm no longer able to access my desktop.

I should add that my TV, which is connected as a second monitor via HDMI, is not receiving any signal.

I get a regular boot sequence followed by my login screen but when I enter my password, all that happens is I get a blank desktop background... the one with Ubuntu 14.10 stamped on it... no Launcher, no desktop, no way to shut down.

As an aside, windows continues to function normally, both monitors are fine.

Any help would be most appreciated. Anyone else having a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is configured such that you are offered a purple screen at boot time with choices to boot a previous version, you may be able to boot successfully, and once in, uninstall or alter your nvidia drivers.  I've read that if you are not automatically offered that menu, that booting with the shift key held down will force that menu to appear.

If you need help reconfiguring or disabling your nvidia drivers I can offer you tips which have worked for me though I don't claim to be an expert.

Comment: Unfortunately, for me at least, when I hold down the shift key while booting, I'm not given the option to boot into previous versions. Grub just loads normally.

Comment: It might not be the shift key, but there should be a way to boot previous versions.  Perhaps its because I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 I see a menu every time I boot and I'm able to boot previous versions.  The more I learn about the latest version of Ubuntu, the less I wish to upgrade.